# Чи існують ступені порівняння дієприкметників?

Tags: дієприкметники

Чи можна від дієприкметників, наприклад, **читаний**, **подертий** утворити найвищі ступені порівняння — **найчитаніший**, **найподертіший**? У мене не вийшло знайти правил, які б регулювали ці випадки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Від «чистого» дієприєприкметника ми, мабуть, не можемо утворювати ступені порівняння.

Але, наскільки я розумію, такі слова як *читаний*, *подертий* не завжди вважаються «чистими» дієприкметниками — залежно від відтінку значення й ролі в реченні (і, звісно, позиції мовознавця), їх можуть вважати як дієприкметниками, так і прикметниками.

#### Подертий

Наприклад, [«Словник української мови» в 11 томах](http://sum.in.ua/s/podertyj) розрізняє *подертий* як дієприкметник і *подертий*, що використовується в значенні прикметника:

> ПОДЕ́РТИЙ, а, е.
>
> 1. Дієпр[икметний] пас[ивний] мин[улого] ч[асу] до подерти 1. На землі лежала довга, місцями подерта, місцями полатана буда [верх халабуди] (Наталія Кобринська, Вибр., 1954, 76); Не спиться Івану — до ранку спокою йому не знайти, подерту в походах шкірянку вже знають безсонні пости (Микола Упеник, Вірші.., 1957, 148); Майже всі [бійці] були вже обшарпані, закривавлені, подерті колючими гілками (Олесь Гончар, III, 1959, 104);
>    // **у знач[енні] прикм[етника]**. Подерте листя з дерев, збита трава й поламані квіти ніби обмилися свіжою водою [після граду] (Наталія Кобринська, Вибр., 1954, 143); Прихильник мужицького царства замислювався, поглядаючи на свої подерті, потріскані ноги (Михайло Стельмах, I, 1962, 503).
> 2. **у знач[енні] прикм[етника]**. Дірявий, драний. Зверху сипав і сипав дрібний сухий сніг, наче борошно з подертого сита (Зінаїда Тулуб, В степу.., 1964, 220); На те він і кравець, щоб подертий жупан носити! (Українські народні прислів'я та приказки, 1955, 62); Коли я боялася тих злиднів, то се не тому, що мене лякав холод, голод, пошарпані вбрання, подерті черевики (Леся Українка, III, 1952, 699);  * Образно. Дощ трохи ніби вщух. Поміж подертих хмар виплив щербатий місяць (Іван Цюпа, Назустріч.., 1958, 111).

#### Читаний

Щодо *читаний*, то хоч я не знаю словників, які б трактували його як прикметник, але таке значення легко уявити:

- коли ми кажемо *читаний*, щоб сповістити, що щось (наприклад книгу) читали, то це очевидно дієприкметник (приклад із того ж «СУМ»-11: «Коли вона стала там край стола, погляд її впав знов на той лист, *недавно читаний*» (Леся Українка));
- коли ми кажемо *читаний* у майже тому самому значенні «той, якого (часто) читали», але вживаємо це як характеристику самого предмету (наприклад книги), аніж щоб повідомити про факт читання — можливо, це слово можно інтерпретувати як прикметник (чи принаймні як дієприкметник у ролі прикметника).

У [корпусі «ГРАК-10»](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=lemmarow&lemma=(%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9)%3F%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9) я бачу поодинокі трапляння ступенів порівнняння від *читаний*:

> Те, що Белль належав до найпопулярніших і **найчитаніших** західньонімецьких авторів кінця 1950-1970-их років, пов'язане з тематикою його творів. // Журнал «Сучасність», Мюнхен, 1986, ч. 1, с. 86.
>
> Він належав до **найчитаніших** німецьких авторів, бо в його творах звучить сильна критика нацистської Німеччини та її духового упадку, що ще не викурився з деяких закостенілих німецьких голов, критика дрібноміщанської ментальности, а також Католицької Церкви. // Журнал «Сучасність», Мюнхен, 1986, ч. 1, с. 87.
>
> У міжвоєнній Польщі газета Ilustrowany Kurier Codzienny, **найчитаніша** в добу своєї появи (1926-1930 рр.), «формувала громадську думку в українському питанні, підсилюючи напруження у польсько-українських відносинах». // Журнал «Сучасність», Мюнхен, 1986, ч. 10, с. 74.
>
> Із саквояжа обережно витягли дерев'яну конячку-гойдалку для маленького Яна, старовинні монети — до колекції старшого Яна, кілька пляшок вина для Йозефа, дві коробки з капелюшками (останнє слово паризької моди), мереживний пеньюар, кілька речей верхнього туалету, віяло, пляшечки з олією та парфумами і, нарешті, підбірку книг і журналів, **найчитаніших** в Парижі. // Сергій Шарик «Двічі графиня та двічі генерал», Київ, 2014.

Оскільки трапляння поодинокі (і три з них в одному й тому самому журналі), ми не можемо на 100% ствержувати про нормативність форм *читаніший*, *найчитаніший*. Але мені особисто вони вухо не ріжуть.